# How to convert the column name to display name smartly?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

For example:

- the column name is "sum(sales)", the display name is "Total Sales"
- the column name is "avg(sales)", the display name is "Average of Sales"

Any AI methods can do it?

There are also some special habits in SQL or database design, for example:

- qty means "Quantity"
- the name in the customer table, means "Customer"
- ...

Can above habits are learned by AI?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need AI for this. Simply use a couple of rules to convert it according to the column name.

First split it into the function (sum, avg) and the argument (sales), and then generate the new name accordingly:

- sum -> "Total " + argument
- avg -> "Average of " + argument

etc.

Comment: In database or SQL, some practices have become habitual, for example, c_id means customer_id, qty means quantity, etc. I want to learn the habits with machine, and generate the display name automatically

Comment: It's not worth it. The number of examples involved is too low to get a machine to learn this. Just have a mapping table from name to label; this will be much quicker and more reliable.

Comment: In my case, has too many tables and columns, and the pattern will be reused in different scenario, if mapping the column to display name every time, it is a big job.